# How to work with streaming data using azure functions?

Tags: node.js, api, azure-functions, azure-eventhub, azure-signalr

I have created a realtime solution using Azure services.
It works based on the following architecture.
NSE(National Stock Exchanges) -> AzureFunction -> EventHub ->Azure Stream Analytics -> Power BI.
In the Azure Function, I wrote the following code.

```
module.exports = async function (context, myTimer) {
    var API = require('indian-stock-exchange')
    var NSEAPI = API.NSE;
    let promise = new Promise((resolve,reject)=>{
        NSEAPI.getGainers()
        .then(function (response) { 
            context.log(response['data']); //return the api data
            resolve(response['data'])
    });
    });
    let result = await promise;
    result = JSON.stringify(result['data'])
    return result 
};
```

I'm using the library here and that calls through the HTTP request but for the streaming, this not a right way, can you guys share any suggestion on my code or any changes on architecture workflow.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what exactly is your question? what is not working with your code above that you need to change?

Comment: This what I have done using Azure function, but for streaming, it's not an optimal solution is there any alternative can we use or something like azure SignalR?

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in some of the comments, the challenge here is that I think you want a persistent “web socket” to the stock exchange constantly pushing data to an Event Hub.  Functions by their nature or more short-lived.  So here the code works, but does a bit of a “wake up, do work, go to sleep, repeat” pattern.

For a persistent connection you may have better luck looking into using something like Azure WebJobs, or just running a web app inside of Azure App Services that will be running 24/7 and could create a persistent feed from the stock data to Event Hubs.